# how to clone bigquery datasets

Tags: google-bigquery

We are evaluating bigquery and snowflake for our new cloud warehouse. Does bigquery has a cloning feature built-in? This will enable our developers to create multiple development environments quickly and we can also restore to point-in-time .Snowflake has a zero-copy clone to minimize the storage footprint. For managing DEV/QA environments in bigquery do we need to manually copy the datasets from prod? Please share some insights.

Comment: check - [Copying datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pre-GA feature [Big query data transfer service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#console) to create copies of datasets, you can also schedule and configure the jobs to run periodically so that the target dataset is in sync with source dataset. Restoring to a point in time is available via [FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF in FROM clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#from-clause)

I don't think there is an exact [`snowflake clone`](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowflake-fast-clone/) equivalent on Big query. What  would this mean?

- You `will be charged` for additional storage and for data transfer if its cross-region (pricing equivalent to Compute Engine network egress between regions)
- Cloning is `not instantaneous`, for large tables(> 1 TB) you might still have to wait for a while before you see a new copy is created